# How to modify existing docker-compose file from java code

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, testcontainers

I have a docker-compose file that has few services defined. I want to add another service in the runtime using java code. Are there any libraries or any method to convert docker-compose files into the java object and process it? (what is on my mind was text processing)

Comment: What have you already tried?  ("Is there a library for X" is generally considered off-topic for Stack Overflow; the [help/on-topic] has more details.)

Comment: what was on my mind is text processing. I will include that in the question. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker-compose files use [YAML](https://yaml.org/). So a YAML parser for Java like [eo-yaml](https://github.com/decorators-squad/eo-yaml) should be enough.

Comment: you are correct. I thought about some specific thing for docker-compose YAML. But now I will use jacksonDatabind parser for this. Thank you.